Why is the conductance of an insulator not $0$?
Even diamond, water, etc. have a specific resistance value. So when sufficient voltage is applied,  current does flow through them. But they don't have free electrons like conductors. Water conducts electricity to a small extent even without electrolysis.
How should I explain that sort of phenomena?

It only takes a few electrons to get a very little current to flow - look at the specific resistance values and see that they vary across many orders of magnitude. Also consider that electricity can be conducted by things other than electrons (e.g. ionic conduction).

At finite temperatures there are always thermally activated charge carriers. Diamond conductivity of 10$^{-18}$ per $\Omega$m at room temperature is pretty close to zero.

There are two simple ways (probably more some other user can comment on) this may happen:

Think about this in terms of band theory. An insulator has an electronic band structure with a large energy gap between the valence and conduction bands, a large "band gap". This energy gap is generally >5 eV, and it's very unlikely for an electron in the valence band to jump the gap and enter the conduction band. However, it's not impossible, in fact, under the effect of an electric field, the likelyhood increases. Meaning that some of the $\sim 10^{23}$ electrons in the valence band will jump into the conduction band and therefore a very small current could be measured. This current may very well be something extremely small like a picoampere, but still, a current.

If the voltage is high enough, you may cause a dielectric breakdown of the substance, meaning it stops being a dielectric and starts being a conductor. This happens, fundamentally, because the electric field is strong enough to pull out outer electrons from their atomic bonds, leading to a situation where current flow is possible. In a gas, a sufficiently high voltage may cause ionization of the molecules/atoms like ionizing radiation would. This is a problem, for example, in ionization chambers and radiation detectors based on ionization of gases. Under voltages above $\sim 1000$ V, a constant discharge is a real possibility.


EDIT: I'd like to add a more quantitative view to this answer, in particular, to possibility number 1. Consider an insulator or semiconductor with band gap $E_g$. All the electrons within the material are fermions, they follow Fermi-Dirac statistics
$$f = \frac{1}{\exp\left(\frac{E-\mu}{kT}\right)+1} .$$
What happens if you're at a very low temperature? Then, $E-\mu\gg kT$ and therefore you can approximate the distribution as a Boltzmann distribution
$$f\approx \exp\left(\frac{-(E-\mu)}{kT} \right) .$$
This is a non-degenerate semiconductor, in that the occupation at any energy level $E$ is very low (low chance of it being degenerate). The density of electrons in the conduction band is then
$$n= \int_{E_c}^{\infty} D_e(E) f(E) dE \sim \exp \left(  \frac{\mu-E}{kT}\right).$$
Where $D_e$ is the density of states (you can determine this through other methods). As you can see, there's a non-zero amount of electrons in the conduction band at a temperature $T$. This may be related to the conductivity through Drude theory (as the simplest approach), where $\sigma = ne\mu_e + pe\mu_p$, $\mu$ is the mobility of the charge carriers (electrons $n$ or holes $p$).
You can do all of this for degenerate semiconductors, but the non-degenerate case is simpler mathematically (simpler integrals).

so . to conduct electricity , internal structure of insulator may change? like in case of diamond?
